# ReArrange Pandas DataFrame date columns in date order

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that summarises sales by calendar month & outputs something like:

```
Month   level_0 UNIQUE_ID   102018  112018  12018   122017  122018  22018   32018   42018   52018   62018   72018   82018   92018
0   SOLD_QUANTITY   01  3692.0  5182.0  3223.0  1292.0  2466.0  2396.0  2242.0  2217.0  3590.0  2593.0  1665.0  3371.0  3069.0
1   SOLD_QUANTITY   011 3.0 6.0 NaN NaN 7.0 5.0 2.0 1.0 5.0 NaN 1.0 1.0 3.0
2   SOLD_QUANTITY   02  370.0   130.0   NaN NaN 200.0   NaN NaN 269.0   202.0   NaN 201.0   125.0   360.0
3   SOLD_QUANTITY   03  2.0 6.0 NaN NaN 2.0 1.0 NaN 6.0 11.0    9.0 2.0 3.0 5.0
4   SOLD_QUANTITY   08  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 175.0   NaN NaN
```

I want to be able to programmatically re-arrange the column headers in ascending date order (eg starting 122017, 12018, 22018...).  I need to do it in a way that is programmatic as every way the report runs, it will be a different list of months as it runs every month for last 365 days.

The index data type:

```
Index(['level_0', 'UNIQUE_ID', '102018', '112018', '12018', '122017', '122018',
       '22018', '32018', '42018', '52018', '62018', '72018', '82018', '92018'],
      dtype='object', name='Month')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for only `date`s columns, convert them to `datetime`s and get order positions by [`argsort`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.argsort.html), then change ordering with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['level_0','UNIQUE_ID'])

df = df.iloc[:, pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%m%Y').argsort()].reset_index()
print (df)
         level_0  UNIQUE_ID  122017   12018   22018   32018   42018   52018  \
0  SOLD_QUANTITY          1  1292.0  3223.0  2396.0  2242.0  2217.0  3590.0   
1  SOLD_QUANTITY         11     NaN     NaN     5.0     2.0     1.0     5.0   
2  SOLD_QUANTITY          2     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   269.0   202.0   
3  SOLD_QUANTITY          3     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     6.0    11.0   
4  SOLD_QUANTITY          8     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN   

    62018   72018   82018   92018  102018  112018  122018  
0  2593.0  1665.0  3371.0  3069.0  3692.0  5182.0  2466.0  
1     NaN     1.0     1.0     3.0     3.0     6.0     7.0  
2     NaN   201.0   125.0   360.0   370.0   130.0   200.0  
3     9.0     2.0     3.0     5.0     2.0     6.0     2.0  
4     NaN   175.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Another idea is create month period index by [`DatetimeIndex.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html), so is possible use [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(['level_0','UNIQUE_ID'])

df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%m%Y').to_period('m')
#alternative for convert to datetimes
#df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%m%Y')
df = df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
print (df)
         level_0  UNIQUE_ID  2017-12  2018-01  2018-02  2018-03  2018-04  \
0  SOLD_QUANTITY          1   1292.0   3223.0   2396.0   2242.0   2217.0   
1  SOLD_QUANTITY         11      NaN      NaN      5.0      2.0      1.0   
2  SOLD_QUANTITY          2      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN    269.0   
3  SOLD_QUANTITY          3      NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN      6.0   
4  SOLD_QUANTITY          8      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   

   2018-05  2018-06  2018-07  2018-08  2018-09  2018-10  2018-11  2018-12  
0   3590.0   2593.0   1665.0   3371.0   3069.0   3692.0   5182.0   2466.0  
1      5.0      NaN      1.0      1.0      3.0      3.0      6.0      7.0  
2    202.0      NaN    201.0    125.0    360.0    370.0    130.0    200.0  
3     11.0      9.0      2.0      3.0      5.0      2.0      6.0      2.0  
4      NaN      NaN    175.0      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Lovely - thanks for this.  I am going to opt for option one to keep it nice & simply but may use the second in another context.

Comment: @lmonty - Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)  Btw, good choice. There is also alternative solution if need datetimes `df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%m%Y')`.

Comment: Will do - thanks.  I just realised I have to return it in descending order in another context.  How would I achieve this with argsort?

Comment: @lmonty - Try `df = df.iloc[:, -pd.to_datetime(df.columns, format='%m%Y').argsort()].reset_index()`